# Integrating the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, self-learning, integral-transforms

I am trying to show that $$\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{f(t)}{t} \right\} = - i \int_{- \infty}^w \hat{f}(w') \, d w'.$$

Shouldn't it be

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{f(t)}{t} \right\} = - i \int_{w}^{+ \infty} \hat{f}(w') \, d w'?$$

I remember the Laplace transform analogue,

$$\mathcal{L} \left\{ \frac{f(t)}{t} \right\} = \int_s^{+\infty} F(s') \, ds'.$$

Comment: But the limit isn't in $t$, but in $w$. As you perform $\int_{- \infty}^w e^{-i w' t} \, dw'$ and go to the lower limit, you are performing $$\lim_{b \to - \infty} \frac{e^{-i b t}}{(-it)}.$$ How can I assure this goes to zero?

Comment: sorry, I've overlooked it. :)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for taking your time to try to help me. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $f(t)/t$ is problematic (may fail to be integrable) unless $f(0)=0$. So  we better make this assumption, which on the Fourier side means that  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(w)\,dw = 0$. Therefore, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^a \hat f(w)\,dw = -\int_a^{\infty} \hat f(w)\,dw$$
and either one-sided integral may be used in the transform of $f(t)/t$.

The proof can proceed by writing $f(t) = t g(t)$ and observing that the derivative of ${\hat g}$ is related to $\hat f$.